# Amplify API GraphQL - Unable to query from aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

I have deployed a new GraphQL private API to my aws console. While I am trying to run the query from aws console, I am getting below error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

Here is my query:

```
query MyQuery {
  listData(limit: 10) {
    nextToken
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Hope to find solution soon as my app stopped working. Do you have a valid resolver?

Comment: @YanislavTankov I have managed to connect using DNS. You can refer to this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-private-apis-on-aws-appsync/

Comment: Actually, the problem was with billing. It's silly, but why this message?